# Rails error "undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am very new to Rails and am trying to use <%= render 'form' %> to include this form on posts/index

```
<%= form_for(@post) do |post_form| %>
<% if @post.errors.any? %>
<div id="errorExplanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
  <li><%= msg %></li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <% end %>

<%= post_form.label :name %>: <%= post_form.text_field :name %>
<br/>
<%= post_form.label :subject %>: <%= post_form.text_field :subject %>
 <br/>
<%= post_form.label :email %>: <%= post_form.text_field :email %>
 <br/>
<%= post_form.label :content %>: <%= post_form.text_area :content %>

<%= post_form.submit %>
```

the error caused says undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Comment: Ensure that `@post` variable is not `nil`.

Comment: how can that be done? once more, i am very new to rails

Comment: @BoAlexander By instantiating a post in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is @post is nil

you can use partial like

```
<%= render partial: "form" %>
```

to pass all instance variables coming form controller to the rendered partial